# Need Help: Simulation Stalls When Using 'Repack Bits' Block for Constellation Decoding

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm working on a GNU Radio project, and I'm currently facing an issue with the 'Repack Bits' block that I hope someone can help me with.

Here's the situation: I've successfully decoded a constellation, and I want to use the 'Repack Bits' block to streamline my data. However, as soon as I introduce the 'Repack Bits' block into the flowgraph, the simulation stalls and stops progressing.

I'm a bit puzzled about why the introduction of the 'Repack Bits' block is causing this halt in the simulation. Has anyone experienced something similar or have any insights into what might be causing this?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Interestingly, when I remove the 'Repack Bits' block, although I'm not able to recover my data as expected, the simulation continues without any issues.